# After upgrading from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 packages in apt return a 404

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I googled like an idiot, but I don't find a solution.

I upgraded ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and after

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This errors showing up:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please post this kind of questions on https://askubuntu.com/, it's another site of stackexchange network.

Comment: ok sorry :| I thought this page is for every developement stuff. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by problem by deleting everything from ondrej an reinstalling php and mysql.